# using docker images for mySQL and redmine, how do I resolve "Unknown MySQL server host"?

Tags: mysql, docker, redmine

I am using the docker images supplied at https://hub.docker.com/_/redmine

I have chosen to use MySQL as my database backend. So I have 2 docker containers: MySQL and Redmine, as downloaded from dockerhub.

Following the instructions on the docker/redmine link above, I ran through the commands and found that the redmine docker would not start. Inspecting the docker logs, I see:

> rake aborted!
> Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Unknown MySQL server host redmine (-5)

I thought the 2 dockers were having difficulty talking to each other, so I setup a new docker network for both containers to use:
***docker network create --driver bridge redmine-net***

Adapting the instructions, on the docker/redmine link above, I run

***docker run -d name our-mysql --network redmine-net -e MYSQL_USER=redmine -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=todays-password -e MYSQL_DATABASE=redmine -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=1 -p 3306:3306 mysql:5.7***

***docker run -d name our-redmine --network redmine-net -e REDMINE_DB_MYSQL=redmine -e REDMINE_DB_USERNAME=redmine -e REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD=todays-password redmine:latest***

However, the redmine contain still falls over instantly, with the same error.

**EDIT** Using the *.yml file as provided in the dockerhub redmine instructions works pretty faultlessly.

So the question is: what is the docker-compose method doing that docker run isn't handling?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you thought about using `docker-compose.yaml` for this purpose?

Comment: Thanks Nico, I am trying it with a docker-compose and a *.yml file now. It seems to get round the error "Unknown MySQL server host redmine" and now I have an error "Mysql::Error::ConnectionError: Access denied for user 'redmine@172.21.0.3' (using password: YES) ".

Comment: I see what I have done now. I tried to map the arguments for the `docker run` command into the *.yml file, but the *yml file works exactly as printed in the instructions at [link](https://hub.docker.com/_/redmine) 
Thank you for your suggestion @Nico, clearly `docker-compose` is the better way, I just need to understand more about why it is better than `docker run`

Answer (score 0):

The `REDMINE_DB_MYSQL` arg of the redmine container do reference to the mysql container, so, if you define the database service like **our-mysql**, then set `REDMINE_DB_MYSQL=our-mysql`